# Как отследить переключение RadioButton?

Tags: java, android

у меня есть ArraList, есть допустим 2 элемента.

Как программно отследить какой из radiobutton нажмет пользователь?

Знаю , что если использовать case, то нужно указывать id элемента в разметке, но я же создал программно,как быть?
Как отследить нажатие?

Comment: Чекбоксы или радио баттоны?

Comment: @КириллМалышев поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаёте программно RadioButton, вы можете задать ему id. Можно, к примеру, записывать созданные кнопки в

```
ArrayList<RadioButton> list;
```

Тогда id кнопке можно задавать как размер списка:

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
// Задаём id
radioButton.setId(list.size());
list.add(radioButton);
radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
```

В onCreate задаём RadioGroup слушателя:

```
list = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            //checkedId - индекс кнопки в ArrayList
            RadioButton button = list.get(checkedId);
        }
    });
```

Уже в слушателе, зная id, можно обратиться к самой кнопке.